# Adding numbers before track in views.List?

Tags: spotify

I want to put track numbering in my views.List, is there any option for that or will I have to create a separate numbering and just put it in front of the list?

```
1. Title - Artist
2. Title - Artist
3. Title - Artist
etc
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A List use a Collection object internally. You can access to the Collection with `list.collection`.

```
int numberTracks = list.collection.length;
for (int i=0; i<numberTracks; i++) {
    console.log(i + " " + list.collection.get(i));
}
```

another way,

```
list.collection.data.forEach(function(item, index) {
    console.log(index + " " + item);
});
```

Comment: Ok, but how can i add the numbering to the list.node?

Comment: That's not possible. It would involve changing internal api code. Maybe you can modify that node before adding it to the DOM.